# How to organize correctly a multicolumn table

Tags: multicolumn

I am having some troubles with a multicolumn table. The table should look like this sample inside a word doc: [image]

But the template that i am using is in LaTeX and when i compile the code that i made i receive this: [image]

This is the code, I think the problem is in the centralization.

```
\PassOptionsToPackage{english, main = brazilian}{babel}%% Multilíngue
\PassOptionsToPackage{hyperfootnotes = false}{hyperref}%% Hipertexto extendido

%% Classe de documento e opções
\documentclass[%% Opções: [*] comente para remover; [>] passada para pacotes
  article,%% Tipo de documento: article, book, report, etc. [>]
  a4paper,%% Tamanho de papel: a4paper, letterpaper, etc. [>]
  11pt,%% Tamanho de fonte: 10pt, 11pt, 12pt, etc. [>]
  fleqn,%% Alinhamento de equações à esquerda (comente para centralizado) [>]
  oneside,%% Impressão: oneside (anverso) ou twoside (anverso e verso) [>]
  % twocolumn,%% Texto em duas colunas (comente para uma coluna) [>]
  chapter = TITLE,%% Títulos de capítulos em maiúsculas [*]
  section = TITLE,%% Títulos de seções (secundárias) em maiúsculas [*]
]{abntex2}

\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{changepage}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{array}
\newcolumntype{N}{>{\centering\arraybackslash}m{.5in}}
\newcolumntype{G}{>{\centering\arraybackslash}m{2in}}

\newcommand*{\boldsymbol}[1]{#1}

\begin{document}

\begin{table*}[!htb]
\centering
\caption{Parâmetros obtidos para o ajuste utilizando o modelo de Langmuir.}%
\label{tab:resul}
\begin{tabular}{c c| c c}
\hline
\multicolumn{4}{c}{Modelo de Langmuir}: 
\begin{minipage}{5.5cm}{\begin{equation}\label{eq:Uxy}
\frac{\\Qmax\ K_L Ceq}{\\1\ +K_L Ceq} = Qe
\end{equation}}
\end{minipage} \\
\cline{1-4}
\centering
\multicolumn{1}{c}{\textbf{HDL Calc}} & \multicolumn{3}{c}{\textbf{HDL SDS Calc}}\\
\hline
\multicolumn{1}{c}{Qmax} & K(L/mg) & Qmax(mg/g) & K(L/mg)\\
\hline
\multicolumn{1}{c}{690,6} & 0,011 & 132,3 & 0,136\\
\hline
\end{tabular}
\fonte{Autoria própria (2021).}
\end{table*}

\end{document}
```

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please make your code compilable by adding the documentclass. Also, how is `\fonte` defined?

Comment: You may want to replace `\centering
\multicolumn{1}{c}{\textbf{HDL Calc}} & \multicolumn{3}{c}{\textbf{HDL SDS Calc}}\\ ` with `\multicolumn{2}{c}{\textbf{HDL Calc}} & \multicolumn{2}{c}{\textbf{HDL SDS Calc}}\\ `  to get closer to the expected output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With `{NiceTabular}` of `nicematrix`.

```
% -*- coding: utf-8 ; -*-
\PassOptionsToPackage{english, main = brazilian}{babel}%% Multilíngue
\PassOptionsToPackage{hyperfootnotes = false}{hyperref}%% Hipertexto extendido

%% Classe de documento e opções
\documentclass[%% Opções: [*] comente para remover; [>] passada para pacotes
  article,%% Tipo de documento: article, book, report, etc. [>]
  a4paper,%% Tamanho de papel: a4paper, letterpaper, etc. [>]
  11pt,%% Tamanho de fonte: 10pt, 11pt, 12pt, etc. [>]
  fleqn,%% Alinhamento de equações à esquerda (comente para centralizado) [>]
  oneside,%% Impressão: oneside (anverso) ou twoside (anverso e verso) [>]
  % twocolumn,%% Texto em duas colunas (comente para uma coluna) [>]
  chapter = TITLE,%% Títulos de capítulos em maiúsculas [*]
  section = TITLE,%% Títulos de seções (secundárias) em maiúsculas [*]
]{abntex2}


\usepackage{siunitx}
\sisetup{per-mode=symbol}

\usepackage{nicematrix,tikz}

\begin{document}

\begin{table*}[!htb]
\centering
\caption{Parâmetros obtidos para o ajuste utilizando o modelo de Langmuir.}%
\label{tab:resul}
\begin{NiceTabular}{cccc}[columns-width=25mm,cell-space-limits=4pt]
\hline
\Block{1-4}{Modelo de Langmuir: 
\begin{minipage}{5.5cm}{\begin{equation}\label{eq:Uxy}
\frac{Q_{\text{max}}\ K_L C_{\text{eq}}}{\\1\ +K_L C_{\text{eq}}} = Q_{\text{e}}
\end{equation}}
\end{minipage}} \\
\hline
\RowStyle{\bfseries}
\Block{1-2}{HDL Calc} && \Block{1-2}{HDL SDS Calc}\\
\hline
$Q_{\text{max}}$ & $K$(\unit{\L\per\mg}) & $Q_{\text{max}}$(\unit{\mg\per\g}) & $K$(\unit{\L\per\mg})\\
\hline
690,6 & 0,011 & 132,3 & 0,136\\
\hline
\CodeAfter \tikz \draw (2-|3) -- (last-|3) ;
\end{NiceTabular}
\fonte{Autoria própria (2021).}
\end{table*}

\end{document}
```

[image: Output of the above code]

Answer (score 2):

With `tabularray` package. MWE below reproduce you first image which you like to reproduce by using LaTeX. Since I haven't your document class, in MWE is used standard `article`, however table code will works in your ddocument class too:

```
\documentclass[twocolummn]{article}
\usepackage[skip=1ex]{caption}
\usepackage{tabularray}
\UseTblrLibrary{siunitx} 
\sisetup{per-mode=symbol}

\begin{document}
    \begin{table*}[htb]
    \centering
\caption{Parâmetros obtidos para o ajuste utilizando o modelo de Langmuir.}%
\label{tab:resul}

\begin{tblr}{hlines,vline{3}=solid,
             colspec={*{4}{X[1,c]}},
             row{2} = {font=\bfseries}
             }
\SetCell[c=4]{c} Modelo de Langmuir: $\displaystyle \frac{Q_{\max} K_L C_{\mathrm{eq}}}
                                                         {1 + K_L C_\mathrm{eq}} = Q_\mathrm{e}$    
            &                       &                                   &                       \\
\SetCell[c=2]{c} HDL Calc       
            &                       &   \SetCell[c=2]{c} HDL SDS Calc   &                       \\
$Q_{\max}$  & K(\unit{\L\per\mg})   &  $Q_{\max}$ (\unit{\mg\per\g})    & K(\unit{\L\per\mg})   \\
690,6       & 0,011                 & 132,3                             & 0,136                 \\
\end{tblr}

Fonte: {Autoria própria (2021).}
\end{table*}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

The following should get you closer to the expected output:

[image]

```
\PassOptionsToPackage{english, main = brazilian}{babel}%% Multilíngue
\PassOptionsToPackage{hyperfootnotes = false}{hyperref}%% Hipertexto extendido

%% Classe de documento e opções
\documentclass[%% Opções: [*] comente para remover; [>] passada para pacotes
  article,%% Tipo de documento: article, book, report, etc. [>]
  a4paper,%% Tamanho de papel: a4paper, letterpaper, etc. [>]
  11pt,%% Tamanho de fonte: 10pt, 11pt, 12pt, etc. [>]
  fleqn,%% Alinhamento de equações à esquerda (comente para centralizado) [>]
  oneside,%% Impressão: oneside (anverso) ou twoside (anverso e verso) [>]
  % twocolumn,%% Texto em duas colunas (comente para uma coluna) [>]
  chapter = TITLE,%% Títulos de capítulos em maiúsculas [*]
  section = TITLE,%% Títulos de seções (secundárias) em maiúsculas [*]
]{abntex2}

\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\sisetup{per-mode=symbol}
\usepackage[column=0]{cellspace}
\setlength{\cellspacetoplimit}{4pt}
\setlength{\cellspacebottomlimit}{\cellspacetoplimit}
\begin{document}

\begin{table*}[!htb]
\centering
\caption{Parâmetros obtidos para o ajuste utilizando o modelo de Langmuir.}%
\label{tab:resul}
\begin{tabular}{*{2}{0{wc{2.5cm}}}|*{2}{0{wc{2.5cm}}}}
\hline
\multicolumn{4}{0c}{Modelo de Langmuir: 
\begin{minipage}{5.5cm}{\begin{equation}\label{eq:Uxy}
\frac{\\Qmax\ K_L Ceq}{\\1\ +K_L Ceq} = Qe
\end{equation}}
\end{minipage}} \\
\cline{1-4}
\multicolumn{2}{0c|}{\textbf{HDL Calc}} & \multicolumn{2}{0c}{\textbf{HDL SDS Calc}}\\
\hline
Qmax & K(\unit{\L\per\mg}) & Qmax(\unit{\mg\per\g}) & K(\unit{\L\per\mg})\\
\hline
690,6 & 0,011 & 132,3 & 0,136\\
\hline
\end{tabular}
\fonte{Autoria própria (2021).}
\end{table*}

\end{document}
```

Comment: I am sorry about no putting the documentclass before. Thank you so much for the help, It is perfect! I am going to try to understand better this type of code!